# Как сделать автозаполнение поля из таблицы не повторяющимся?

Tags: php, yii2

Значение поля name сохраняется в таблицу Entity. При новом вводе все значения name подтягиваются автозаполнением из этой таблицы. Проблема состоит в том, что подтягиваются все одинаковые значения. Например, если до этого я 5 раз добавил значение "Наименование" в таблицу, то при вводе значения в поле элементы автозаполнения будут подтягиваться 5 раз как "Наименование". Как сделать автозаполнение уникальным и не повторяющимся?

```
use frontend\models\Entity;
use yii\jui\AutoComplete;

<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->widget(
        AutoComplete::class, [
            'clientOptions' => [
                'source' => Entity::find()->select(['name as label'])->asArray()->all(),
                'minLength'=>'3', 
                'autoFill'=>true,
            ],
            'options'=>[
                'class'=>'form-control'

            ],
        ]
    ) ?>
```

Comment: `select(['distinct name as label'])` ?

Comment: Нет, выкидывает Database Exception 1054 Unknown column 'distinct name'

Comment: Но вы навели меня на верное решение. Работает так: 
    select(['name as label'])->distinct()->asArray()->all()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select(['name as label'])->distinct()->asArray()->all()
```